# .NET: Locking a ToolBarButton without specializing the class

Tags: .net, winforms, components

I am interested in locking a ToolBarButton in .NET 1.1 so that the property `.Enabled = True` is effectively ignored. I have looked at the members of the class and cannot find anything applicable.

I have found the Property Change Notification pattern in my research and it seems to be available only in .NET 3.0. Have anyone implemented something similar in previous versions of .NET? Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you still working with 1.1?

Comment: @Spencer: Maybe because it is not up to him.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a work-around, however it is not a lock behaviour.

I basically delete the ToolBarButton in the ToolBar.Buttons collection. So no matter whether it is enabled or not, the user is not able to click on it. :-)